# Connect to SPSite behind a proxy pnppowershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pnp-powershell, proxy

I need to update listItem in a SharePoint site ( SharePoint2016). 
Actually there is a proxy that cant allow me to access.
the proxy is with login and password.

first I tried the window webClient :

```
    [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
Try {

   Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxxx -UseWebLogin
   Write-Host "Connected" -ForegroundColor Green
   $Site=Get-PnPSite
   write-host "Site: "+$Site.Title;
    $web=Get-PnPWeb
    write-host "web: " + $web.Title
    write-host "web: " + $web.id
    Write-Host "Connected" -ForegroundColor Green

}
catch {
    Write-Host "Not able to connect" -ForegroundColor Red
    $Error
}
```

The error is :

> Get-PnPSite : Cannot contact site at the specified URL
>   https://xxxx Au caractère Ligne:5
>   : 10
>   +    $Site=Get-PnPSite .....

the other way is using the Invoke-webrequest:

```
#proxy supports NTLM/AD authentication $Wcl = new-object System.Net.WebClient $Wcl.Headers.Add(“user-agent”, “PowerShell
 Script”) $Wcl.Proxy.Credentials =
[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

$Test=Invoke-WebRequest https://xxx
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxx -UseWebLogin
   Write-Host "Connected" -ForegroundColor Green
   $Site=Get-PnPSite
```

error:

> Get-PnPSite : Cannot contact site at the specified URL
>   Au caractère Ligne:1 : 7
>   + $Site=Get-PnPSite
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPSite], ClientRequestException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Site.GetSite

Any idea !